# AsymptoticOutputTracking for output with boundary condition

Tags: dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems, asymptotics

I want to try asymptotic output tracking, but with inequality.

There is a differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}(-x^4)$

With output $y=\frac{d}{dx}(-x^4)$,
The output should strive for $0$, i.e. $r_1=0$.

Question: how to make a inequality $x>0$ ?

I will be glad to any advice and help.

Answer (score 2):

The system

```
asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{{-4 x^3}, {{1}}, {-4 x^3}}, {x}];
```

A controller

```
fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, 0, p]
```

> $\left\{-\frac{1}{3} x \left(p+12 x^2\right)\right\}$

And the state response of the closed-loop system for an initial value $x0$.

```
csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[asys, fb];
StateResponse[{csys, {x0}}, {0}, t]
```

> $\left\{\text{x0}\  e^{\frac{p t}{3}}\right\}$

The inequality $x>0$ will be satisfied as long as $x0>0$.

And for any $p<0$ the system will be stable and the output will go the zero.

```
OutputResponse[{csys, {x0}}, {0}, t]
```

> $\left\{-4 \text{x0}^3 e^{p t}\right\}$

```
Limit[%, t -> ∞, Assumptions -> p < 0]
```

> 0

Comment: And how to impose a condition like this? $1<x<2$

Comment: And I especially want to understand how to work with outputs like $y=Sign[x]$

Comment: The theory is based on the state-space being a smooth manifold. It cannot deal with discontinuities. The control technique also does not impose constraints a priori. But what is evident from the analysis of the problem is that the constraint $1<x<2$ is inconsistent with the output reaching $0$.